# check if text input matches one item inside one of multiple arrays within if and else if statements in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement, input

I have a page in a application where I want to have specific images pop up if a specific text is entered by the user. I tried with one example and it worked, but **now that I added several variables and their array rows, it does not work**. *I can't tell exactly what mistake I have made here, I am guessing it's something to do with the nesting with the if and else if condition/statements*

**HTML**

```
      <form>
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Type or tap on the microphone above">
      </form>
      <div class="imageContainerSearchPage"> 


            <img id="toast_018" class="hiddenElement" src="animsAll/Anims_018_Toast.gif">
            <img id="nobaloons_014" class="hiddenElement" src="animsAll/Anims_014_no baloons.gif">
            <img id="wegotastory_019"  class="hiddenElement" src="animsAll/Anims_019_Button_We got a story_textandbook.gif">
            <img id="parisIsBurningButton_021" class="hiddenElement" src="animsAll/Anims_021_Paris is Burning Button.gif">
    </div>
    <!--[•VIDEO BACKGROUND•]-->
    <video  autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="videos/music_saint_etienne_only_love_cropped_370x660.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT: not working**

```
     $( "input" )
          .keyup(function() {
            var value = $( this ).val();
            var no = ["sixties", "sixty", "sixtys"];
            var weGotAStory = ["we", "got", "story"];
            var sandwich = ["sandwich", "grilled"];
            var parisIsBurningButton = ["paris", "burning"];
            var toast = ["toasted", "toast", "toasts"];
          if($.inArray(value, no) !== false) {
              $("#nobaloons_014").show().delay(10000).fadeOut();
          } else if ($.inArray(value, weGotAStory) !== false) {
            $("#wegotastory_019").show().delay(10000).fadeOut();
          } else if ($.inArray(value, parisIsBurningButton) !== false) {
            $("#parisIsBurningButton_021").show().delay(10000).fadeOut();
        } else ($.inArray(value, toast) !== false) {
          $("#toast_018").show().delay(10000).fadeOut();

        }

          })
```

**JAVASCRIPT: working (single IF statement)**

```
     $( "input" ).keyup(function() {
            var value = $( this ).val();
            var no = ["no", "nope", "nos"];
          if($.inArray(value, no) !== false) {
              $("#nobaloons_014").show().delay(10000).fadeOut();
         }

      })
```

Comment: inArray gives you either index or -1 if not found then why comparing it with false. Hence the statement you have used will always return true!

Comment: I changed to the -1 and so forth and it did not workl.   I made the compromise just now of eliminating the arrays and keeping it to one word. This worked well. I  will do this for the time being and later on will try to see how I can put the arrays back in. (I am doing this for a test so it does not have to be exact, just as long as at least one word makes the image pop up.

Answer (score 0):

I compromised with the arrays and took them out because nothing else was working. This works to make the hidden image corresponding to the string pop up but it's not exactly what I wanted (it does not offer the multiple word option w/o the arrays).

```
$( "input" )
  .keyup(function() {
    var value = $( this ).val();
    var sixties = "sixties";
    var paris = "paris";
    var weGotAStory = "story";
  if (value == sixties) {
    $("#button1960s_002").show().delay(10000).fadeOut();
  }   else if (value == paris) {
      $("#parisIsBurningButton_021").show().delay(10000).fadeOut();
    } else if (value == weGotAStory) {
        $("#wegotastory_019").show().delay(10000).fadeOut();
      }

  })
```